# Multiplicate set of dates for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, multiplication

There are two tables

- Table 1 (1 column name_employee, 50 rows) with all unique employee names
- Table 2 (1 column date, 10 rows) with all unique dates

I would like to create a new dataset in SQL Server Management Studio in which the set with unique dates is duplicated for each unique employee. This would result in a dataset with 2 columns (name_employee and date) and 50x10 rows.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use CROSS JOIN.The CROSS JOIN joins every row from the first table (T1) with every row from the second table (T2). In other words, the cross join returns a Cartesian product of rows from both tables.

```
 SELECT
     name_employee,date
    FROM
     Table1
    CROSS JOIN Table2;
```